# Position with css absolute and relative

Tags: css, html

i have a little project but it have long html code, becouse of that i will give link to it.
link: http://1zh.us/examples/position.html

this is what i want:
when i scroll left-right-left i want yellow div to bee fixed (not changing position) but when i scroll up-down-up i want green div to bee fixed.
i have tryed all combinations of fixed, relative and absolute positioning but without result.
i hope that this can be done with html5 and css.

look at the sample on the link and scroll it up-down left-right to see exactly what i want
thank you for your help...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body><div id="randevu_sag" style="position:fixed; top:25px; left:235px; bottom:0px; right:0px; overflow:auto;">
<div id="rust" style="left:0px; top:0px; height:27px; width:1863px; background-color:green;">
<div style="position:relative; width:49px; height:25px; float:left; border-right:solid 1px #9a4b9d; border-bottom:solid 2px #000;">Saat</div>
<div style="position:relative; margin-left:2px; width:299px; height:25px; float:left; border-right:solid 1px #9a4b9d; border-bottom:solid 2px #000;">Bolum1</div>
<div style="position:relative; margin-left:2px; width:299px; height:25px; float:left; border-right:solid 1px #9a4b9d; border-bottom:solid 2px #000;">Bolum2</div>
<div style="position:relative; margin-left:2px; width:299px; height:25px; float:left; border-right:solid 1px #9a4b9d; border-bottom:solid 2px #000;">Bolum3</div>
<div style="position:relative; margin-left:2px; width:299px; height:25px; float:left; border-right:solid 1px #9a4b9d; border-bottom:solid 2px #000;">Bolum4</div>
<div style="position:relative; margin-left:2px; width:299px; height:25px; float:left; border-right:solid 1px #9a4b9d; border-bottom:solid 2px #000;">Bolum5</div>
<div style="position:relative; margin-left:2px; width:299px; height:25px; float:left; border-right:solid 1px #9a4b9d; border-bottom:solid 2px #000;">Bolum6</div>
</div>

<div id="ralt" style="left:0px; top:27px; width:1863px">
<div style="position:absolute; left:0px; width:49px; float:left; border-right:solid 1px #9a4b9d; background-color:yellow;">
<div id="1383890400" style="border-bottom:solid 1px #000; height:2225px; width:50px; overflow:hidden;"></div>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; left:51px; float:left;">
<div style="position:absolute; left:0px; width:299px; float:left; border-right:solid 1px #9a4b9d;">
<div id="1383890400" style="border-bottom:solid 1px #000; border-left:solid 5px blue; height:2225px width:292px; overflow:hidden;">birinci</div>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; left:302px; float:left; width:299px; border-right:solid 1px #9a4b9d;">
<div id="1383890400" style="border-bottom:solid 1px #000; border-left:solid 5px blue; height:2225px; width:292px; overflow:hidden;">ikinci</div>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; left:604px; float:left; width:299px; border-right:solid 1px #9a4b9d;">
<div id="1383890400" style="border-bottom:solid 1px #000; border-left:solid 5px blue; height:2225px; width:292px; overflow:hidden;">ucuncu</div>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; left:906px; float:left; width:299px; border-right:solid 1px #9a4b9d;">
<div id="1383890400" style="border-bottom:solid 1px #000; border-left:solid 5px blue; height:2225px; width:292px; overflow:hidden;">dorduncu</div>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; left:1208px; float:left; width:299px; border-right:solid 1px #9a4b9d;">
<div id="1383890400" style="border-bottom:solid 1px #000; border-left:solid 5px blue; height:2225px; width:292px; overflow:hidden;">besinci</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add position:fixed for your yellow div and  green div in your css

Comment: Just as a side note `id="1383890400"` is invalid, prepend it with something, even `id="row_1383890400"` would be better.

Comment: j08691 i had edited my post. thank you for warning me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add:

```
yellow.div{
position:fixed;

}

green.div{
position:fixed;
}
```

?

Comment: His markup won't allow for this, especially since fixed will want to start from the top left of the window. He could do it for the green since its in a container `rust` but that as far as this will get him.

Comment: position fixed is not solution for me. becouse it fixed div both left-right and up-down movement

Answer (score 0):

This is my recommendation for your yellow column

```
<div style="position:fixed; width:49px; float:left; border-right:solid 1px #9a4b9d; background-color:yellow;">
```

or in CSS

```
element.style {
position: fixed;
width: 49px;
float: left;
border-right: solid 1px #9a4b9d;
background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: i want to reduce my code and put it here as soon as possible.
But fixed is not what i am looking for. becouse when i put position:fixed; it is fixed both x and y location of div. what i want is when i scrolling up-down the yellow div will go up-and down but not left and right. also when i scroll it left right yellow div will be stable while green one will go left and right.